# How can I modify the "schedule scan" to be disabled? (don't have permission to disable)

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, scheduled-tasks

After running powercfg /requests, it seems that `\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\MoUsoCoreWorker.exe` is responsible for my computer not being able to sleep/stay asleep.

I've located the process to `schedule scan` within the task scheduler, but am unable to disable it as I get an error

> the user account you are operating under does not have permission to disable this task

Comment: Are you an administrator of the machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

Download [`PsExec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
extract it to a directory.

1. Right-click `cmd` *"Run as Administrator"*.
2. `cd` to the folder where you extracted `PSExec`
3. Copy the command `"psexec.exe -i -s %windir%\system32\mmc.exe /s taskschd.msc"` and paste in the `cmd` window, press enter.
4. In the Task Scheduler Library, Right click the task and click **Disable**.

Comment: This can disable it. But after a while, Windows will enable it again automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`MoUsoCoreWorker` stands for "USO Core Worker".
The shorthand USO stands for "Update Session Orchestrator".

The Orchestrator is part of Windows Update. Its job is to verify that all the
components of Windows Update are running well. If you have turned Windows Update
off, it will turn it on again.

Apparently in your case it is waking up the computer for a check by Windows Update.
It is supposed to afterward return the computer to the sleep state,
but evidently Microsoft has here a bug.

Disabling the Orchestrator is not a good idea.
You may configure Windows Update to do its check during the day, to an hour
when the computer is usually not asleep.